# Get NW LatLng From Ground Overlay After Rotation

Tags: android, google-maps

I need to get the NW LatLng from a rectangle bounding a Ground Overlay. Using mOverlay.getBounds() will get me the point I need before rotation (getBounds ignores rotation). 
[image]

This is the Ground Overlay, with the exact LatLng I need being the point in red. When it sits perfectly North/South (image on the left) I can get the point no problem using getBounds(). After rotating the image, I now need whatever the point is that is the NW corner of the North/South facing rectangle that contains my rotated Ground Overlay (red dot of image on the right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to assume you are using 'bearing' to rotate the overlay image and the anchor of the image is the center.  Also, since the map is a modeling a sphere, when you say rectangle we're really assuming a 2d plane tangential to the sphere at the image center (non-rotated).

This explanation makes a simplifying assumption that the rotation angle is less than pi/2 radians and is in the clock-wise direction.

None of this is new so no credit taken - but tried my best to adapt to your problem.

In summary this approach converts the original rectangle (non-rotated) in WGS-84 coordinate system to an x/y coordinate system (centered at origin), computes new x/y of rotated, select corners using trig, derive x/y of upper-left of super-rectangle and translate the result back to WGS-84 spherical coordinate system.

```
// convert your rotation value (bearing clockwise) to radians

// Using the bounding rectangle (which is of the non-rotated image) compute distance 
// between nw and ne corner (width) and nw and sw corner (height) (in meters).  
// The purpose of this is to establish an x/y coordinate system with origin being 
// the center of the non-rotated image.

// Compute the corner coordinates of original bounding rectangle in an x/y coordinate 
// system using the center as the origin (0,0) e.g. divide NW-NE width by 2 change sign as needed.  Units are meters

// Compute rotated NW corner (x`,y`) (in x/y system) using original NW corner(x/y) 
// and bearing:

//     x` = x * cos(bearingInRadians) + y * sin(bearingInRadians) and y` = -(x * sin(bearingInRadians)) + y * cos(bearingInRadians)

// Compute the y-distance from original NW corner (x/y) to new NW corner (x`,y`) 
// (subtract the y's)

// Compute latitude of super-bounding by using SphericalUtil.computeOffset using 
// original NW lat-lng as 'from', and y-distance (meters) as distance and heading as 0 (north-up).

// Compute the rotated SW corner(x``,y``) (in x/y system) in the same manner 
// as the NW corner above.

// Compute the x-distance from original SW corner (x/y) to new SW corner

// Compute longitude of super-bounding rectangle by using
// SphericalUtil.computeOffset using original NW lat-lng as 'from', and 
// x-distance (meters) as distance and heading as 270.
```

Overcoming the simplifications means picking the proper corners to use and which maps to latitude and longitude.

I'd expect something like this has already been implemented but hopefully this helps explain what is needed.  Happy hunting.

And here's an implementation of above:

```
    GroundOverlayOptions goo = new GroundOverlayOptions();
    BitmapDescriptor bd = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.rectangle);
    goo.image(bd);
    goo.position(latLng, 1000F);
    GroundOverlay go = mMap.addGroundOverlay(goo);
    LatLngBounds llb = go.getBounds();
    LatLng ne = llb.northeast;
    LatLng sw = llb.southwest;

    PolylineOptions po = new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(llb.northeast.latitude,llb.southwest.longitude))
            .add(llb.northeast)
            .add(new LatLng(llb.southwest.latitude,llb.northeast.longitude))
            .add(llb.southwest)
            .add(new LatLng(llb.northeast.latitude,llb.southwest.longitude));
    Polyline polyline = mMap.addPolyline(po);

    MarkerOptions mo = new MarkerOptions();
    mo.position(new LatLng(ne.latitude,sw.longitude));
    mMap.addMarker(mo);
    goo.bearing(25.0F);
    GroundOverlay go2 = mMap.addGroundOverlay(goo);

    double rads = Math.toRadians(25.0);

    float[] result = new float[1];
    Location.distanceBetween(llb.northeast.latitude, llb.southwest.longitude, llb.northeast.latitude, llb.northeast.longitude, result);
    float width = result[0];
    Location.distanceBetween(llb.northeast.latitude, llb.northeast.longitude, llb.southwest.latitude, llb.northeast.longitude, result);
    float height = result[0];

    float upperLeftX = -(width / 2);
    float upperLeftY = (height / 2);

    float lowerLeftX = upperLeftX;
    float lowerLeftY = -upperLeftY;

    double newX = (upperLeftX * cos(rads) + upperLeftY * sin(rads));
    double newY = (-(upperLeftX * sin(rads)) + upperLeftY * cos(rads));

    double deltaY = abs(newY - upperLeftY);
    LatLng newLat = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(llb.northeast, deltaY, 0.0);

    double newX2 = (lowerLeftX * cos(rads) + lowerLeftY * sin(rads));
    double newY2 = (lowerLeftX * Math.sin(rads) + lowerLeftY * cos(rads));

    double deltaX = abs(newX2 - lowerLeftX);
    LatLng newLng = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(llb.southwest, deltaX, 270.0);

    MarkerOptions mo2 = new MarkerOptions();
    mo2.position(new LatLng(newLat.latitude, newLng.longitude));
    mMap.addMarker(mo2);
```

And the result:

[image]

Notes

1. There is error introduced when projecting the surface of a sphere using linear scaling but is significantly reduced when working with small areas.

References:

1. For the trig I referenced: [rotate rectangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384186/calculate-new-positon-of-rectangle-corners-based-on-angle)
2. Android stuff (1): [Spherical Util](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html)

Comment: This is a beautiful answer. Just what I needed, thanks you so much!